# How can I get the previous source code line number which calls logging in-directly?

Tags: python, logging

I have this code:

log.py

```
from .color import Color
import logging

class Log:
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(levelname)-8s [%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%d-%m-%Y:%H:%M:%S',
                        level=logging.INFO)
    logger = logging.getLogger('anywordcanbethis')

    @classmethod
    def warning(self, msg):
        Log.logger.warning(Color.fg.yellow + msg + Color.reset)

    @classmethod
    def error(self, msg):
        Log.logger.error(Color.fg.red + msg + Color.reset)

    @classmethod
    def debug(self, msg):
        Log.logger.info(Color.fg.pink + msg + Color.reset)
```

As you can see, what this does is setting logging options in this class so that my another projects can easily just use logger in the way I want to use like:

```
import Log

Log.warning("BLAHBLAH") ->
31-05-2018:18:06:45,313 WARNING  [log.py:12] "BLAHBLAH" (yellow)
Log.error("BLAHBLAH") ->
31-05-2018:18:13:43,481 ERROR    [log.py:16] "BLAHBLAH" (red)
```

the problem is, the printed line number will always be log.py:12 <- like this, which I don't want. I want to check what file called Log.warning, Log.error..., which might be in the one level higher stack.

What options should I try on logging?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `FindCaller()`, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.findCaller):

> Logger.findCaller()
>
> ```
> Finds the caller’s source filename and line number. Returns the filename, line number and function name as a 3-element tuple.
>
> Changed in version 2.4: The function name was added. In earlier versions, the filename and line number were returned as a 2-element
> tuple.
> ```

For interest sake, here is the `findCaller` method(I notice that this is returning a 2 element tuple thus this is from < 2.4):

```
def findCaller(self):
    """
    Find the stack frame of the caller so that we can note the source
    file name and line number.
    """
    rv = (None, None)
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    while frame:
        sfn = inspect.getsourcefile(frame)
        if sfn:
            sfn = os.path.normcase(sfn)
        if sfn != _srcfile:
            #print frame.f_code.co_code
            lineno = inspect.getlineno(frame)
            rv = (sfn, lineno)
            break
        frame = frame.f_back
    return rv
```

---

I found the latest version:

```
def findCaller(self, stack_info=False):
    """
    Find the stack frame of the caller so that we can note the source
    file name, line number and function name.
    """
    f = currentframe()
    #On some versions of IronPython, currentframe() returns None if
    #IronPython isn't run with -X:Frames.
    if f is not None:
        f = f.f_back
    rv = "(unknown file)", 0, "(unknown function)", None
    while hasattr(f, "f_code"):
        co = f.f_code
        filename = os.path.normcase(co.co_filename)
        if filename == _srcfile:
            f = f.f_back
            continue
        sinfo = None
        if stack_info:
            sio = io.StringIO()
            sio.write('Stack (most recent call last):\n')
            traceback.print_stack(f, file=sio)
            sinfo = sio.getvalue()
            if sinfo[-1] == '\n':
                sinfo = sinfo[:-1]
            sio.close()
        rv = (co.co_filename, f.f_lineno, co.co_name, sinfo)
        break
    return rv
```

Comment: I found problem. findCaller doesn't directly show the line that my Log.warning() is called. Instead, it showed me the position of where the function that includes Log.warning() is executed